# How to use other ssh tool connect to Vagrant easily

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

When execute `vagrant up`, server will show all information you need to know, ssh is one of them, but if I clear the screen, I will lose the information of ssh, the port is random, I can only access it by vagrant ssh, but I want to use other powerful tool to do that, can I keep the port to 22 or do anything let tool connect to it easily?

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to it via its IP address on port 22. Atleast thats how I connect to my vagrant machine.

You might want to set up a private network through your vagrant machine though, so you can have a static IP. [Vagrant Docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html)

Comment: I cant connect to ip if set `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"`, but failed in `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"`, but I want to connect to inner MySQL, how come?